# How Elasticsearch relevance score gets calculated?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am using `multi_match` with `phrase_prefix` for full text search in Elasticsearch 5.5. ES query looks like

```
{
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: {
        multi_match: {
          query: "butt", 
          type: "phrase_prefix", 
          fields: ["item.name", "item.keywords"], 
          max_expansions: 10
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting following response

```
[
  {
    "_index": "items_index",
    "_type": "item",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 0.61426216,
    "_source": {
      "item": {
        "keywords": "amul butter, milk, butter milk, flavoured",
        "name": "Flavoured Butter"
       }
     }
   },
   {
     "_index": "items_index",
     "_type": "item",
     "_id": "1",
     "_score": 0.39063013,
     "_source": {
       "item": {
         "keywords": "amul butter, milk, butter milk",
         "name": "Butter Milk"
       }
     }
   }
 ]
```

Mappings is as follows(I am using default mappings)

```
 {
   "items_index" : {
     "mappings" : {
       "parent_doc": {
         ...
         "properties": {
           "item" : {
             "properties" : {
               "keywords" : {
                 "type" : "text",
                 "fields" : {
                   "keyword" : {
                     "type" : "keyword",
                     "ignore_above" : 256
                   }
                 }
               },
               "name" : {
                 "type" : "text",
                 "fields" : {
                   "keyword" : {
                     "type" : "keyword",
                     "ignore_above" : 256
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           } 
         }
       }
     }
 }
```

How `item` with `"name": "Flavoured Butter"` getting higher score of `0.61426216` against the document with `"name": "Butter Milk"` and score `0.39063013`?

I tried applying boost to `"item.name"` and removing `"item.keywords"` form search fields getting same results.

How scores in Elasticsearch works? Are above results correct in terms of relavance?

Comment: could you give us the mapping of the index? because i'm getting a different scoring value of `0.37598053` for doc with `"name": "Flavoured Butter"`

Comment: @ChandraPraneethN I am using default mappings(added in question). Only thing is `item` is nested document inside its parent, But that should not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The scoring for `phrase_prefix` is similar to that of `best_fields`, meaning that score of a document is the score obtained from the best_field, which here is `item.keywords`.

So, `item.name` isn't adding to score

Refer: [multi-match-types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types)

You can use 2 `multi_match` queries to combine the score from `keywords` and `name`.

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [{
            "multi_match": {
               "query": "butt",
               "type": "phrase_prefix",
               "fields": [
                  "item.keywords"
               ],
               "max_expansions": 10
            }
         },{
            "multi_match": {
               "query": "butt",
               "type": "phrase_prefix",
               "fields": [
                  "item.name"
               ],
               "max_expansions": 10
            }
         }]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there way to rewrite this query to get correct results, applying boost on `item.name` or somthing?

Comment: You can use 2 `multi_match` queries. Updated the answer.